# Material emitting only in dark parts of an object

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, light, emission

I would really need to know if it is possible to make an object have a material, that emmits only in the lit parts of an object. The dark parts would remain dark. I am using Eevee with Bloom turned on and so I need the lit parts to glow.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this can be achieved with a `Shader to RGB` node. This lets you have a diffuse shader to compute which parts are lit, which you can then pass into an emission shader to make it glow.

**Nodes:**

[image: nodes]

**Result:**

**[image: result]**

I use a color ramp to separate between the lit and unlit areas, and then feed that into a mix shader so the lit parts are shaded with the emission, and the unlit with the diffuse shader.

If you want to achieve a smoother gradient, you can pass the value of the color ramp into the strength of the emission, so that the more lit parts also emit more.

Comment: just realized ive got an extra emssion node in there, you can ignore that one.